# Get access token facebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook, access-token, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to figure out, how to log in to facebook account and get **access token** so I can post into my groups.

To create a `GraphAPI` instance, I need to check **access_token** I need and put it into the code.

I'm curious whether is it possible to use **username** and **password** to get the `access_token` automatically so the program can be used by more users.

```
oauth_access_token = 'ACCESS TOKEN WHICH I HAVE TO GET FROM https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/..../'

def post_to_1_group(user,password,post):

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
    groups = graph.get_object("me/groups")
    group_id = groups['data'][1]['id'] # select the first group I'm in

    graph.put_object(group_id, "feed", message=post)
```

This code works but it doesn't use `user` and `password` arguments. I have to check my **access_token** everytime I want to run the program.

Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible to use username and password to get an access token

Comment: I don't understand. It should be possible because you are able do it logging in facebook via your browser and then get the token manually. The thing is that I want to do login and get the token not manually but automatically. Maybe you mean that fb does not allow it?

Comment: Correct. There is no API for that. You need to show the dialog for the user so they can input username and password